# Remove event listener from an element with parameters

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'd like to remove an event listener from an element but its function has to take a parameter and it seems to not work. I was trying to find a solution on internet but anyone seems to have the same problem as me.

The role of the function is to simply change the visibility of the element

It doesn't make much sense to remove the listener immediatly but it's only for the example.

```js
function createHoverEqElts() {
 slotElts.forEach(function(slot, i) {
  if(existValueElts[i].value == "true") {
   let infoElt = document.createElement('div');
   infoElt.style.position = "relative";
   infoElt.style.bottom = "71px";

   slot.appendChild(infoElt);
   slotListenersElts.push(infoElt);

   slot.addEventListener('mouseover', _slotListener(infoElt));
   slot.removeEventListener('mouseover', _slotListener(infoElt));
   slot.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    infoElt.style.visibility = "hidden";
   });
  }
 });
}

let _slotListener = function(elt) {
 return function() {
  elt.style.visibility = "visible";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you return a function for some reason. You should pass a function that does something. Try this.

```
let _slotListener = function(elt) {
  elt.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

And then do this. In this scenario, you can also pass null instead of this, try either one.

```
slot.addEventListener('mouseover', _slotListener.bind(this, infoElt));
```

Comment: Yes I already tried this one but if I do that, the function will be immediatly executed when the code will be read. That's why usually anyone write the () at the end of the function

Comment: Oh, yeah. I see you problem. I'll edit my answer now.

Comment: The code is executed immediatly even with the .bind function. Nevermind, I'll try to do it in a other way, thanks.

Comment: You're probably doing something else, or it's getting called from someplace else, where you forgot to put the bind. Because this method returns a function, and unless you put parentheses next to it, it won't execute.

Answer (score 0):

Since your function returns an anonymous function, you lose its reference. `removeEventListener` needs the same occurrence to work properly.

In other words `_slotListener(infoElt) == _slotListener(infoElt)` will always return false, so `removeEventListener('event', _slotListener(infoElt))` will never work.

Store the function returned by `_slotListener()` somewhere and use it back to remove the event. In your example, it could be in a variable. In a more complex example, it could be in an object with some kind of reference or in a property in the DOM element.

```
var callback = _slotListener(infoElt); // save reference
slot.addEventListener('mouseover', callback);
slot.removeEventListener('mouseover', callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot remove the event listener effectively is because the function that you are passing to addEventListener is not the same as the function that you are passing to removeEventListener. JavaScript cannot compare two functions that have the exact same contents and tell they are the same function. Every single time you call `_slotlistener`, it creates a *new* function that is not the same as functions that were previously returned by `_slotlistener`. Instead, the proper way to do this would be to assign the result of `_slotlistener` to a variable, and then pass that variable into addEventListener and removeEventListener. For example,

```
var myListenerFunc = _slotListener(elt);
slot.addEventListener("mouseover", myListenerFunc);
slot.removeEventListener("mouseover", myListenerFunc);
```